# How to configure DB Navigator for Jetbrains PHPStorm and WebStorm

Tags: database, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm, navigator

I need to set up a connection in the DB Navigator plugin for PHPStorm in a mac (snow leopard). It asks me for the route of a library that implements the java.sql.Driver class. I just don't have any idea of where is it. Any advice?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

> Instructions

1. Install DB Navigator Plugin via menubar >> Settings >> Plugins >>
   Available-Tab
2. Download MySQL jdbc connector from here >>
   http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
3. Unpack MySQL jdbc connector to a directory of your choice
4. Restart PHPStorm / WebStorm
5. Add a DB via menubar >> DB Navigator >> Settings >> Connection-Tab >> Plus-Button
6. Enter the parameters for your connection (see below for possible entries for a local MySQL DB)

> Possible parameters for a local MySQL DB

- Name: name of choice (localhost)
- Description: additional info of choice (dbname)
- Driver Library: path to the .jar file (that is the directory used in step 3)
- Driver: preferred driver (most likely the standard driver will do >> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)
- URL: connection URL with a jdbc reference (e.g.: **jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/**)
- UserName: db username of choice (root)
- Password: db password of choice (root)

Comment: I had some trouble getting this figured out until I realized that my server is not listening on any sockets that could be reached from the outside internet.

Comment: i lost you from step 4, i installed db navigator from plugins, but how to open, i mean from where to open, any shortcut for it?

Comment: @SyedHaiderHassan after you installed DB Navigator plugin & restart PHPStorm, there should be a menu **DB Navigator** between *Window* and *Help* on the menubar

Comment: @Rocoo: Thanks, restarting the program has been added as step 4 of the instructions

Comment: Using Oracle JDBC driver I don't get any options at all in the select driver dropdown. Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: for SQLite do most PHPStorm users just run the Firefox plugins to read them?  Does PHPStorm have a SQLite compatible DBNavigator?

Comment: Thanks, that answer just helped me a lot. Thanks for contributing it Bruiser.

Answer (score 16):

Just make sure you added **jdbc:mysql://** before hostname. That solved my problem.

```
jdbc:mysql://my-db-url.com
```

Comment: This also solves the "driver refused to create connection for this configuration. no failure information provided" error.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you don't need to install third-party DB Navigator plug-in, as database functionality is available in PhpStorm out of the box, see `Tools` | `Data Sources`.

Add new data source, it will allow to choose the database and the driver, and will download the required database drivers automatically.

Comment: Thank you i found it and although i don't see the databases to explore at least i made the conection. Thank you again, i'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Installed unpacked MySQL Connector J files here >
c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector J

And there need to us >
mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar

Copy to >
c:\Documents and Settings[YOUR_COMP].WebIde70\config\jdbc-drivers\

In MySQL Database connection choose
Drivers >> MySQL >> click on PLUS and select

> >
>   c:\Documents and Settings[YOUR_COMP]\.WebIde70\config\jdbc-drivers\mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar

Also need Database Support plug-in turn ON! (Settings >> IDE Settings >> Plugins)

p.s. Actually for PHPStorm 7

Answer (score 0):

Download **mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar** file and set Driver Library path for that jar file.

Then the Intellij idea will automatically load the Driver which is **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**.

Then set URL as **jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/**

Finally enter valid user name and a password.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly view this picture. I hope it may help you a little bit.

1. There is a driver files missing error at below of this image, click this  it will download required driver for you.
2. Database: your database name.
3. User : your database user name and password.
4. Then click test connection.I hope it will give you successful message.

[image]