# DB Navigator for Jetbrains PHPStorm and WebStorm via SSH

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, phpstorm, webstorm

I can connect to my db no problem via the standard PhpStorm / WebStorm db window by using the "configure ssh" option. I would like to use the DB Navigator though as it has many more features.

Did this : [How to configure DB Navigator for Jetbrains PHPStorm and WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434742/how-to-configure-db-navigator-for-jetbrains-phpstorm-and-webstorm)

However, my issue is that I can only connect to my DB's via a SSH tunnel. They are not publicly accessible and I do not have a VPN to the network.

Can I use the DB Navigator plugin? I cannot seem to find a place to set up the SSH tunnel.

Comment: Please note that Database support plugin is not available in WebStorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database Navigator plugin is not available in WebStorm...

### UPDATE 4/30/19:

The plugin is now available for WebStorm:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator

Comment: Database Navigator is now available for WebStorm: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ Idea you have bundled "Database support" plugin (probably the same in other JB ides), where you can configure data source over ssh tunnel. Do to this you have to:

1. Open "Database" plugin window
2. Add -> Data Source -> MySQL
3. Enter database properties:

   - host: localhost
   - username and passowrd to databse
4. Click "Configure SSH"

   - check Use SSH tunnel
   - fill connection details

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. Yes this is for the native DB support. But I was referring to the DB Navigator plugin, which is not supported for WebStorm. Thanks for your answer anyway!  :)